# What's the strength of caratheodory extension theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, reverse-math

There is a theorem, which says that any sigma finite measure on a ring can be extended uniquely on the sigma ring generated by it.
I want to know what's the weakest axiom to prove it.
Is it RCA0, WKL0, ACA0, or stronger?